# Autowiring multiple data sources with jpa and non-jpa characteristics using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-batch, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-boot

I have two database configuration javaconfig classes - one for JPA purposes with transactionManager() and entityManagerFactory() @Bean methods and one config class for non-JPA JDBCTemplate based query submission to access data from that database. The overall idea is to read using JDBCTemplate to read data and persist the data, after transformation, into the JPA based datasource. I am using Spring Boot to enable auto configuration. My test fails with:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type:
```

I have both `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in my `build.gradle`. My gut feeling is that the two data sources are in collision course with each other. How do I enforce the use of each of these datasources for the two use-cases that I mentioned earlier - one for JPA and another for JDBCTemplate purposes?

Details (Added after Dave's reply):

My service classes have been annotated with `@Service` and my repository classes have `@Repository`. Service uses repository objects using `@Autowired` though there are some services that are JDBCTemplate-based for data retrieval.

More complex depiction of my environment goes as follows (logically): `JDBCTemplate(DataSource(Database(DB2)))`--> `Spring Batch Item Reader;Processors; Writer --> Service(Repository(JPADataSource(Database(H2))))`. Spring batch item processors connect to both databases using services. For spring batch, I am using a H2 Job repo database (remote) to hold job execution details. Does this make sense? For Spring batch, I am using `de.codecentric:spring-boot-starter-batch-web:1.0.0.RELEASE`. After getting past the `entityManagerFactory` bean not found errors, I want to have control over the wiring of the above components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's anything to do with the data sources. The log says you have a JPA repository for a type that is not an `@Entity`. Repositories are automatically scanned from the package you define `@EnableAutoConfiguration` by default. So one way to control it is to move the class that has that annotation to a different package. In Boot 1.1 you can also set "spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false" to switch off the scan if you don't want it. Or you can use `@EnableJpaRepositories` as normal.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to switch off the scanning as suggested, I get `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type repository`.

Comment: Without seeing all your code it's really impossible to interpret random one-line log statements. If you need a repository, why are you disabling them? Maybe you need to share a project.

Comment: I will add you to my github collaborators. What is your github user name?

Comment: I have added dsyer to my repo: https://github.com/naruraghavan/NetStarContentBatchMigrationWithBootAssistant

Comment: I can see the code. You have Spring Data repositories and entities, but I can see that you are manually configuring the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` (and a load of other things that Boot would do for you), and you are injecting a "entitymanager.packages.to.scan" that doesn't point to a package with any `@Entity` classes.

Comment: I added `entityManagerFactory` to have control over wiring JPA to a specific datasource. I do have the package scan pointing a set of domain `@Entity` classes.

Comment: I just found out after looking at my application.properties. You are right! My package scan is pointing to an old location before I refactored my code. Let me change and see

Comment: Now, this is the error message I am seeing: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3:`

Comment: One of your `DataSources` has to be `@Primary` (as mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources)).

Comment: For details of how to specify the location of your `@Entities` [see also in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-entity-classes).

Comment: I included the `@Primary`. But the batch job repository autowiring was looking at the primary datasource for batch job tables. Therefore, I merged the batch job tables with my primary database to solve the issue. I will experiment more to feed a separate datasource for batch job purposes. For now, I am good to go. Thanks for your help!!